# Vuex/Redux store pattern - sharing single source of data in parent and child components that require variations of that data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, redux, store

I understand the benefits of using a store pattern and having a single source of truth for data shared across components in an application, and making API calls in a store action that gets called by components rather than making separate requests in every component that requires the data.

It's my understanding that if this data needs to change in some way, depending on the component using the data, this data can be updated by calling a store action with the appropriate filters/args, and updating the global store var accordingly.

However, I am struggling to understand how to solve the issue whereby a parent component requires one version of this data, and a child of that component requires another.

Consider the following example:

In an API, there exists a GET method on an endpoint to return all people. A flag can be passed to return people who are off sick:

GET: `api/people` returns `['John Smith', 'Joe Bloggs', 'Jane Doe']`

GET: `api/people?isOffSick=true` returns `['Jane Doe']`

A parent component in the front end application requires the *unfiltered* data, but a child component requires the *filtered* data. For arguments sake, the API does not return the isOffSick boolean in the response, so 2 separate requests need to be made.

Consider the following example in Vue.js:

```
// store.js

export const store = createStore({
  state: {
    people: []
  },
  actions: {
    fetchPeople(filters) {
      // ...
      const res = api.get('/people' + queryString);
      commit('setPeople', res.data);
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setPeople(state, people) {
      state.people = people;
    }
  }
});
```

```
// parent.vue - requires ALL people (NO filters/args passed to API)

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.setPeople();
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'people'
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['setPeople']),
  }
}
```

```
// child.vue - requires only people who are off sick (filters/args passed to API)

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.setPeople({ isOffSick: true });
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'people'
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['setPeople']),
  }
}
```

The parent component sets the store var with the data it requires, and then the child overwrites that store var with the data *it* requires.

Obviously the shared store var is not compatible with both components.

What is the preferred solution to this problem for a store pattern? Storing separate state inside the child component seems to violate the single source of truth for the data, which is partly the reason for using a store pattern in the first place.

Edit:

My question is pertaining to the architecture of the store pattern, rather than asking for a solution to this specific example. I appreciate that the API response in this example does not provide enough information to filter the global store of people, i.e. using a getter, for use in the child component.

What I am asking is: where is an appropriate place to store this second set of people if I wanted to stay true to a store focused design pattern?

It seems wrong somehow to create *another* store variable to hold the data just for the child component, yet it also seems counter-intuitive to store the second set of data in the child component's state, as that would not be in line with a store pattern approach and keeping components "dumb".

If there were numerous places that required variations on the people data that could only be created by a separate API call, there would either be a) lots of store variables for each "variation" of the data, or b) separate API calls and state in each of these components.

Comment: If response from `api/people` does not include `isOffSick` data, what exactly are you asking? You can't filter `people` based on `isOffSick`, so you definitely need to get that data from the server.

Comment: My question pertains more to the actual architecture of the store pattern rather than this specific problem. Sorry, I should have made that clearer in the question, which I have now updated.

Comment: If your store contains ALL the people and whether or not they are `offSick`, you should use a getter which simply filters `people` objects based on their `isOffSick` property. If the server responds with a single page of `people`, you need to make a separate req for offSick, because you don't want to display in child the offSick from first page of all people. You want to display the first page of offSick people.

Comment: And no, it's not wrong to store separate sets of data into the store, even if they originally point to the same entries in the database. The real problem here is you don't have enough info in the original set of data, so you need to get the extra information from the server. Yes, you could augment/replace the original set of `people` with the additional information, but that will likely make your app logic more complex, therefore harder to scale/maintain going forward. Answering your question requires more context around your data, which you haven't provided.

Comment: You've totally mis-understood my question.

There is no more context around my data. The question isn't about that data, it's about the best approach when using a specific design pattern/architecture.

The question assumes that there isn't enough data from the server, and if that is the case, where - if following a store pattern - is the best location for the second set of data.Anyway, you've somewhat answered my question in your previous comment: "it's not wrong to store separate sets of data into the store, even if they originally point to the same entries in the database." Thank you.

Comment: I don't think I misunderstood the question. Considering it, I'd probably ask other questions first: If `api/people` will never be paginated (which is to say you'll never have more than tens of thousands of people), probably the best approach is to return `isOffSick` info in the `api/people` response. In which case, you can handle the offSick client side. In any other case (if `api/people` is paginated or if it doesn't contain `isOffSick` data), you need to make the second request. With this new data, you could patch/replace the original `people`, but I personally wouldn't recommend it...

Comment: ... because you'll find yourself in a situation where you need to store whether or not the original data has been patched. And if you ever do go above the pagination threshold, you'll find it a lot harder to implement pagination (or other types of filtering) to your now considerably more complex store. Whereas two sets of data in memory is literally nothing to the browser.

Comment: "With this new data, you could patch/replace the original people, but I personally wouldn't recommend it because..."

That's kind of what I was asking! Although I was more referring to the clarity of the implementation rather than performance. Of course, if this were a real world scenario, I would obviously request that the API returns the isOffSick property. I was only adamant that this wasn't a viable solution because that wasn't the point of the question. Perhaps a better example could have been given (e.g. pagination, as you said), so apologies for that. Not sure how I can...

Comment: ... mark your previous comments as the correct answer :)

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question with what you found useful in my comments. I'm more interested in helping out, than I am in collecting rep. To me it looks like the best approach in your case is to include `isOffSick` data in the `api/people` response. This allows making one single initial server request and then handle filtering (e.g: search, pagination) client side. This model is viable when dealing with less than 20k records. In which case you don't need to replace anything in store state anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to tao I've found what I'm looking for:

The best approach would be to return the isOffSick property in the API response, then filtering the single list of people (e.g. using a store getter), thus having a single source of truth for all people in the store and preventing the need for another API request.

If that was not possible, it would make sense to add a secondary store variable for isOffSick people, to be consumed by the child component.